# Lazy Loading, React Router V6 and nested routes getting an error: "A component suspended while responding to synchronous input."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-context

My use case is as follows: I build a web application, and I use `react-router@6` to build the application's routes. I'm using the `RouterProvider` from `react-router-dom`. Then, I configured some routes, together with nested routes also. Each route, **including nested routes**, is lazy loaded. The problem I had by now is, when I navigate from page to another, the application screen flushes. To solve it, I used this technique: https://github.com/HanMoeHtet/route-level-code-split

In short, I use `React.Suspense` with a `fallback` value of the current rendered page. This way, when I navigate to other page (which is lazy loaded), the fallback element is the same page I navigated from, and this is how the screen does not flushes anymore.

I'm going to provide my whole code here, but most code blocks are going to be duplicated from https://github.com/HanMoeHtet/route-level-code-split
So you can look there instead if you want

Here is my entry file of the application, `index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './App';
import store from './store/app';

import './i18n/config';
import './styles/custom.scss';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);

root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
);

export default root;
```

Then, my `App.tsx` file is (I removed some irrelevant logic..):

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import type { PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import type { IAutoAuthResponseData } from '@exlint.io/common';

import { backendApi, cliBackendApi } from './utils/http';
import type { IAuthPayload } from './store/interfaces/auth';
import type { AppState } from './store/app';
import { authActions } from './store/reducers/auth';

import AppView from './App.view';

interface IPropsFromState {
    readonly isAuthenticated: boolean | null;
}

interface IPropsFromDispatch {
    readonly auth: (loginPayload: IAuthPayload) => PayloadAction<IAuthPayload>;
    readonly setUnauthenticated: () => PayloadAction;
}

interface IProps extends IPropsFromState, IPropsFromDispatch {}

const App: React.FC<IProps> = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps>) => {
    return <AppView isAuthenticated={true} />;
};

App.displayName = 'App';
App.defaultProps = {};

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    auth: authActions.auth,
    setUnauthenticated: authActions.setUnauthenticated,
})(React.memo(App));
```

And my `App.view.tsx` file is:

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import RouterBuilder from './App.router';

interface IProps {
    readonly isAuthenticated: boolean | null;
}

const AppView: React.FC<IProps> = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps>) => {
    const routes = useMemo(() => {
        return RouterBuilder(props.isAuthenticated);
    }, [props.isAuthenticated]);

    return <RouterProvider router={createBrowserRouter(routes)} fallbackElement={null} />;
};

AppView.displayName = 'AppView';
AppView.defaultProps = {};

export default React.memo(AppView);
```

My `App.router.tsx` file is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, type RouteObject } from 'react-router-dom';

import AppLayout from './App.layout';
import { startProgress } from './services/progress-bar';
import { preloader } from './utils/http-backend';

const Auth = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/Auth'));
const ExternalAuthRedirect = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/ExternalAuthRedirect'));
const AccountSettings = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/AccountSettings'));
const CliAuth = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/CliAuth'));
const CliAuthenticated = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/CliAuthenticated'));
const NotFound = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/NotFound'));
const Account = React.lazy(() => import('@/containers/AccountSettings/Account'));
const SecretManagement = React.lazy(() => import('@/containers/AccountSettings/SecretManagement'));

const RouterBuilder = (isAuthenticated: boolean | null) => {
    const unAuthorizedRoutes: RouteObject[] = [
        {
            path: '',
            element: <Auth />,
        },
        {
            path: 'auth',
            element: <Auth />,
        },
        {
            path: 'external-auth-redirect',
            element: <ExternalAuthRedirect />,
        },
    ];

    const authorizedRoutes: RouteObject[] = [
        {
            path: 'account-settings',
            element: <AccountSettings />,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    element: <Navigate to="account" replace />,
                },
                {
                    path: 'account',
                    element: <Account />,
                },
                {
                    path: 'secret-management',
                    element: <SecretManagement />,
                    loader: async () => {
                        startProgress();

                        await preloader('/user/secrets');

                        return null;
                    },
                },
                {
                    path: 'secret-management/new',
                    element: <NewSecret />,
                },
                {
                    path: 'secret-management/*',
                    element: <Navigate to="secret-management" replace />,
                },
                {
                    path: '*',
                    element: <Navigate to="account" replace />,
                },
            ],
        },
    ];

    const generalRoutes: RouteObject[] = [
        {
            path: 'cli-auth',
            element: <CliAuth />,
        },
        {
            path: 'cli-authenticated',
            element: <CliAuthenticated />,
        },
        {
            path: 'not-found',
            element: <NotFound />,
        },
        {
            path: '*',
            element: isAuthenticated === null ? null : <NotFound />,
        },
    ];

    const routes = [
        {
            element: <AppLayout />,
            children: [...(isAuthenticated ? authorizedRoutes : unAuthorizedRoutes), ...generalRoutes],
        },
    ];

    return routes;
};

export default RouterBuilder;
```

This is my `App.layout.tsx` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

import EDNotification from '@/ui/EDNotification';

import FallbackProvider from './helpers/FallbackProvider';

interface IProps {}

const AppLayout: React.FC<IProps> = () => {
    return (
        <FallbackProvider>
            <Outlet />

            <div id="backdrop-root" />
            <div id="overlay-root" />

            <EDNotification />
        </FallbackProvider>
    );
};

AppLayout.displayName = 'AppLayout';
AppLayout.defaultProps = {};

export default React.memo(AppLayout);
```

This my `FallbackProvider.tsx` file:

```
import React, { Suspense, useCallback, useMemo, useState } from 'react';

import { FallbackContext } from './context/fallback';
import type { FallbackType } from './interfaces/types';

interface IProps {}

const FabllbackProvider: React.FC<IProps> = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps>) => {
    const [fallbackState, setFallbackState] = useState<FallbackType>(null);

    const updateFallback = useCallback((fallback: FallbackType) => {
        setFallbackState(() => fallback);
    }, []);

    const renderChildren = useMemo(() => {
        return props.children;
    }, [props.children]);

    return (
        <FallbackContext.Provider value={{ updateFallback }}>
            <Suspense fallback={fallbackState}>{renderChildren}</Suspense>
        </FallbackContext.Provider>
    );
};

FabllbackProvider.displayName = 'FabllbackProvider';
FabllbackProvider.defaultProps = {};

export default React.memo(FabllbackProvider);
```

And this is the related context:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

import type { FallbackContextType } from '../interfaces/types';

export const FallbackContext = createContext<FallbackContextType>({
    updateFallback: () => {
        return;
    },
});
```

Then I have this `Page.tsx` wrapper:

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

import { usePage } from '@/hooks/use-page';
import { endProgress, startProgress } from '@/services/progress-bar';

interface IProps {}

const Page: React.FC<IProps> = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps>) => {
    const { onLoad } = usePage();
    const location = useLocation();

    const render = useMemo(() => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-useless-fragment
        return <>{props.children}</>;
    }, [props.children]);

    useEffect(() => {
        onLoad(render);
    }, [onLoad, render]);

    useEffect(() => {
        endProgress();

        return () => startProgress();
    }, [location]);

    return render;
};

Page.displayName = 'Page';
Page.defaultProps = {};

export default Page;
```

and the `use-page.ts` hook is:

```
import { useCallback, useContext } from 'react';

import type { FallbackType } from '../helpers/FallbackProvider/interfaces/types';
import { FallbackContext } from '../helpers/FallbackProvider/context/fallback';

export const usePage = () => {
    const { updateFallback } = useContext(FallbackContext);

    const onLoad = useCallback(
        (component: FallbackType | undefined) => {
            if (component === undefined) {
                component = null;
            }

            updateFallback(component);
        },
        [updateFallback],
    );

    return { onLoad };
};
```

Now, for each page in `App.router.tsx` (each page loaded from `pages` folder **only** and not `components` folder!), I do this thing:

```
import React from 'react';

import Auth from '@/containers/Auth';
import Page from '@/helpers/Page';

interface IProps {}

const AuthPage: React.FC<IProps> = () => {
    return (
        <Page>
            <Auth />
        </Page>
    );
};

AuthPage.displayName = 'AuthPage';
AuthPage.defaultProps = {};

export default AuthPage;
```

And finally, this is my `progress-bar.ts` service:

```
import nProgress from 'nprogress';

nProgress.configure({
    showSpinner: false,
});

export const startProgress = () => {
    nProgress.start();
};

export const endProgress = () => {
    nProgress.done();
};
```

Then I try to load my website but I get this error:

```
Unexpected Application Error!
A component suspended while responding to synchronous input. This will cause the UI to be replaced with a loading indicator. To fix, updates that suspend should be wrapped with startTransition.

throwException@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LCEHA6P5.js?v=0485a108:14217:43
handleError@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LCEHA6P5.js?v=0485a108:19030:29
renderRootSync@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LCEHA6P5.js?v=0485a108:19115:26
recoverFromConcurrentError@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LCEHA6P5.js?v=0485a108:18732:42
performSyncWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LCEHA6P5.js?v=0485a108:18875:28
flushSyncCallbacks@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LCEHA6P5.js?v=0485a108:9135:30
../../node_modules/.pnpm/react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js/ensureRootIsScheduled/<@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LCEHA6P5.js?v=0485a108:18623:21

 Hey developer 

You can provide a way better UX than this when your app throws errors by providing your own errorElement props on <Route>
```

This happens every time I navigate, to any URL in website.

---

### First try

I started using `startTransition` functionb in several places related with `FallbackProvider.tsx` file, on this row: `<Suspense fallback={fallbackState}>{renderChildren}</Suspense>`.

So that's what I tried:

In `FallbackProvider.tsx` I changed the `updateFallback` function to:

```
    const updateFallback = useCallback((fallback: FallbackType) => {
        startTransition(() => {
            setFallbackState(() => fallback);
        });
    }, []);
```

In `Page.tsx` I modified the 2 `useEffect` to:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        startTransition(() => {
            onLoad(render);
        });
    }, [onLoad, render]);

    useEffect(() => {
        startTransition(() => {
            endProgress();
        });

        return () => startProgress();
    }, [location]);
```

And in `use-page.ts` file I modified the `onLoad` function to:

```
    const onLoad = useCallback(
        (component: FallbackType | undefined) => {
            if (component === undefined) {
                component = null;
            }

            startTransition(() => {
                updateFallback(component!);
            });
        },
        [updateFallback],
    );
```

These changes did not help me, and the error is the same.

---

### Update for issue

I changed this line of code in `use-page.ts` file:
`updateFallback(component);` to `return null;` and the issue does not occur anymore. But of course.. now I canceled the point of the code (now when I return null, there won't be the fallback I want - the renderer page).

Comment: @DrewReese
Oh, sorry. Not. I will provide this service code now. It does not use any redux.

Comment: The error says to use a [startTransition](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#starttransition) to handle this logic. I'm not very familiar with this feature of `react@18` though.

Comment: @DrewReese any specific code block to add this `startTransition` function? I added it to several places related with the `React.Suspend.fallback` key but it did not help and the error still present

Comment: I believe the transitions are more related to enqueueing state updates. The [useTransition](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usetransition) docs might be a little more informative. It's not immediately clear what state update needs to be, or is getting, suspended. Maybe the `fallbackState` state?

Comment: @DrewReese

Well, I wrapped the `setFallbackState` with `startTransition`. Actually, you can check out what I've tried completely in the `First try` heading in my question.

Comment: With this much code to consider you should provide a link to the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided on just using this flow:
Every route has `loader` key where I force the lazy loading:

```
            loader: async () => {
                startProgress();

                await import('./pages/AccountSettings');

                endProgress();

                return null;
            },
```

This is how each route looks like now. I did it also to nested routes.
Regarding the `startProgress` and `endProgress`, I'm using the `n-progress` package and it seems to handle multiple calls perfect. By that I mean that the doing `startProgress` and `endProgress` in a parents components and its children still works, though you might think it can lead to issues.

I removed any other code block.
You can see the full code here:
https://github.com/Exlint/dashboard

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your problem is exactly, but since you have an issue with Suspense here is how it works:
when you go to a page for example when we first start our application it opens the home page aka `'/'` page, if you use Suspense it will only try to download the content of this page this way it loads faster because it doesn't load any unnecessary code, and when you change to another page it will cache what is downloaded and try to download the next page, for example, let's say we try to get to `'/about'` page, then it will try to download the code related to About page, and each time you change the pages it will download more code and while the code is downloading it shows the fallback of the Suspense.

but in case you have nested routes and you don't want to suspense the whole application you can wrap the nested routes in another suspense.

here is a code example:

```
const authorizedRoutes: RouteObject[] = [
        {
            path: 'account-settings',
            element: <Suspense fallback='nested fallback'> //this way when you change pages between Account or SecretManagement, etc... it'll render the nested fallback instead of you other fallback 
                       <AccountSettings />
                     </Suspense>,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    element: <Navigate to="account" replace />,
                },
                {
                    path: 'account',
                    element: <Account />,
                },
                {
                    path: 'secret-management',
                    element: <SecretManagement />,
                    loader: async () => {
                        startProgress();

                        await preloader('/user/secrets');

                        return null;
                    },
                },
                {
                    path: 'secret-management/new',
                    element: <NewSecret />,
                },
                {
                    path: 'secret-management/*',
                    element: <Navigate to="secret-management" replace />,
                },
                {
                    path: '*',
                    element: <Navigate to="account" replace />,
                },
            ],
        },
    ];
```

you can do that for your other routes too.

Comment: I do use `Suspense` in my current code. Why would these extra `Suspense` element help? Wrapping `Suspense` over each item seems overwhelming solution.